# ¿Cómo ejecutar elemento.click() sobre un botón en específico por medio de python - selenium cuando existen tres botones iguales en una misma página?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selectores-css

Deseo poder realizar la acción de dar clic sobre cualquiera de los botones "seleccionar" que se muestran en la imagen adjunta, pero estos cuentan con exactamente la misma información para la class, href, text...
He intentado con varios tipos de selectores, por medio de XPATH, CLASS_NAME, LINK_TEXT, TAG_NAME y por medio del último he logrado obtener la siguiente información:

> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a6fbe2db8712c42436508245bc35dcb1", element="7BFE6DCBBBBCB52E55F22FAB3C8286DD_element_41")>

Pero con esta no he logrado realizar nada ya que según lo que encontré esta información cambiará para cada vez que se corra el script.

[image: Características de los botones en el código, los tres tiene lo mismo, excepto el "data-se"]

[image: Botones en la UI]

Adjunto sección del código:

```html
<div class="authenticator-button" data-se="okta_verify-totp"><a data-se="button" class="button select-factor link-button" href="#">Seleccionar</a></div>
<div class="authenticator-button" data-se="okta_verify-push"><a data-se="button" class="button select-factor link-button" href="#">Seleccionar</a></div>
<div class="authenticator-button" data-se="webauthn"><a data-se="button" class="button select-factor link-button" href="#">Seleccionar</a></div>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no usar el _data-se_ del `div` padre de cada botón? Parecen ser únicos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda, pude lograrlo por medio del data - se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con el html que compartes, parece que el atributo `data-*` del div padre podría servir para identificar a cada uno de los botones. Por ejemplo, deberías poder buscar usando XPATH con algo como:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-se='okta_verify-push']/a").click()
```

para el segundo botón en este caso.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me ayudó a solucionar el problema que tenía

Comment: @gigi18 no olvides entonces [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta.